# How to work around broken transitive jsDependencies?

Tags: scala, sbt, scala.js, webjars

The webjar ecosystem has recently been broken.

See https://github.com/webjars/webjars/issues/1789

`org.webjars.npm:react:16.2.0` depends on `org.webjars.npm:loose-envify:[1.1.0,2)` which now includes newly released version 1.4.0 which depends on `org.webjars.npm#js-tokens;[3.0.0,4),[4.0.0,5)` which fails to resolve.

How can I force the version of either `org.webjars.npm:loose-envify` to 1.3.1, or `org.webjars.npm#js-tokens` to 3.0.2?

I tried https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react/commit/6446d73464f5f4836d1af1aff5f750325f8e24f7 but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answered [here](https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react/commit/6446d73464f5f4836d1af1aff5f750325f8e24f7#commitcomment-29695130) by https://github.com/rpiaggio (thank you!)

Use `dependencyOverrides += "org.webjars.npm" % "js-tokens" % "3.0.2"`